# how to open windows explorer through a hyperlink?

Tags: html, windows-explorer

How can I open a folder in windows explorer through a html site with a hyperlink?

This example just opens the folder in the webbrowser:

```
<a href="file:///folder">Open Folder in Windows Explorer</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be done for security reasons. It is deliberately prevented.